# Hamiltonian in control theory

Tags: optimal-control

In the wikipedia article
[Hamiltonian (control theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(control_theory)), I don't understand why $H(q,u,p,t)$ doesn't depend on $\dot{q}$.
Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Can you explain why you came to that conclusion after looking at that page? Because to me it seems that page does say that the Hamiltonian depends on $q$ (namely $x=q$ and $\lambda=p$).

Comment: Or are you referring to that $L(q,u,t)$ does not depend on $\dot{q}$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I did a mistake. I wanted t say $\dot{q}$. I edited the question. Thanks. What I don't understand is why H(q,u,p,t) doesn't depend on $\dot{q}$ even though I understand L doesn't depend on $\dot{q}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in the optimal control problem formulation $\dot{q}$ is a function of $q$, $u$ and $t$. This can be shown by using the fact that $q=x$ and

$$
\dot{x} = f(x,u,t).
$$

The Hamiltonian can still be defined in terms of $\dot{q}$, however $\dot{q}$ can also be expressed in terms of $q$, $u$ and $t$. And after substituting in that expression for $\dot{q}$ the Hamiltonian does not explicitly depend on $\dot{q}$.

Comment: Oh, this makes sense. Thank you.